# When building a report - Edit Row Level Formula to Sub Null value from Picklist

Tags: formula, reporting, report-formula

In my report I'm trying to substitute "null" value from populating in my report to have "not matched" there are 2 existing picklist values that would appear otherwise.

I've tried

```
CASE(Lead.LD_Account_Coverage_Type__c, 
     "Territory","Territory", 
     "Named", "Named",
     else, "Not Matched")
```

- Error when encoding row-level formula: Syntax error. Missing ')'

I've also tried

```
IF(ISPICKVAL(Lead.LD_Account_Coverage_Type__c,
   "Territory","Territory", "Named", "Named",else, "Not Matched")
```

and I get the same error- anyone know what the correct formula is?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure of `CASE` is:

```
CASE(Lead.LD_Account_Coverage_Type__c, 
 "Territory","Territory", 
 "Named", "Named",
 "Not Matched") /* this is the otherwise path */
```

there is no `else` token